# DDEV OCI runtime exec failed (TYPO3 `ddev typo3cms` command)

Tags: typo3, ddev, colima

Recently I have issues with DDEV. It’s across different git repositories, so I think that has to do with DDEV or Colima.

- ddev version v1.21.6
- colima version 0.5.5
- macOS Ventura 13.4.1
- Macbook Pro M1

```
ddev typo3cms cache:flush
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec /mnt/ddev_config/.global_commands/web/typo3cms: operation not permitted: unknown
```

```
ddev typo3cms database:updateschema safe
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec /mnt/ddev_config/.global_commands/web/typo3cms: operation not permitted: unknown
Failed to run typo3cms database:updateschema safe: exit status 126
```

After `ddev poweroff` `ddev start`, the above commands work again. But after a while (15 Minutes) I see the same error messages again.

Comment: depending on your version of `helhum/typo3-console` the command `typo3cms` doesn't exist anymore. I don't know why it's in global commands, but it's likely configured in the folder .ddev.

Comment: It's also possible that you did configure it in your home folder of the host system `~/.ddev`

Comment: The call to the command might come from some scheduler task respectively cronjob.

Comment: When this happens you can `ddev exec ls -l /mnt/ddev_config/.global_commands/web/typo3cms` to see if the file exists and is executable. You can then `ddev ssh` and see if you can run it.  But do see if typo3cms exists, and if it doesn't we should get rid of the ddev custom command.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! I now ran `colima delete`, then `colima start` as suggested in https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/blob/main/docs/FAQ.md#issues-after-an-upgrade

Comment: If you don't get it sorted out, come over to Discord and we'll do a live debugging screenshare session. https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k

Comment: Make absolutely sure that your project is in the home directory. Colima by default only mounts things in the home directory; DDEV tries to warn you about that in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to run `colima delete`.

Before you do that, try the following step suggested by @rfay

> You can also experiment with a new profile for colima for  debugging reasons (without losing anything) with

```
colima stop
colima start mynewprofile --cpu 4 --memory 6 --disk 100 --vm-type=qemu --mount-type=sshfs --dns=1.1.1.1
```

> And you can then switch between profiles using `docker context use colima` (for the default profile) or `docker context use colima-mynewprofile`